# C# Custom Map Routes / View Paths / Link Generation

Tags: c#, routes, actionlink, html.actionlink, custom-routes

**Issue/Try 1:**
I have a custom route map:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "User Profile",
    url: "User/{userId}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { Areas = "User", controller = "Kpi", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

If i manually navigate to the URL `/User/f339e768-fe92-4322-93ca-083c3d89328c/Kpi/View/1` the page loads with a View Error: `The view 'View' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations`.

**Issue/Try 2:**
Stopped using the custom route and set up my controller as instead:

```
    [RouteArea("User")]
    [RoutePrefix("{userId}/Kpi")]
    public class KpiController : BaseUserController
    {
        [Route("View/{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> View(string userId, int? id = null)
        {
            [...]
        }
    }
```

This now works i can navigate to the URL and the View displays fine.

**Issue for both:**
Although I can navigate manually to both and they load I can't seem to generate the URL correctly using `ActionLink`:

`@Html.ActionLink(kpi.GetFormattedId(), "View", "Kpi", new { Area = "User", userId = Model.Id, id = kpi.Id }, null)`

It generates: `/User/Kpi/View/1?userId=f339e768-fe92-4322-93ca-083c3d89328c` instead of `/User/f339e768-fe92-4322-93ca-083c3d89328c/Kpi/View/1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**URL Mapping**
After some time i have found the solution for the custom mapping i was adding in the main `RouteConfig.cs` and not in the `Area` Registration. Moving the `MapRoute` to the `Area` works correctly and without the `RouteArea`, `RoutePrefix` and `Route` attributes in the Controller.

**Area Registration**

```
public class UserAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
{
    public override string AreaName => "User";

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            name: "User",
            url: "User/{userId}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        context.MapRoute(
            "User_default",
            "User/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new {action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
        );
    }
}
```

**Links**
Instead of using `ActionLink` i am now using `RouteLink`.

```
@Html.RouteLink("KPIs", "User", new { Controller = "Kpi", Action = "Index", userId = Model.Id })
```